# Injection provider with injected MultivaluedMap (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

The Jersey docs give an example of [how to inject HttpSession on resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e16983). How should I inject (or otherwise gain access to) form parameters sent on requests with "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"? I see that these are passed as [parameters on methods, and do not seem to be annotated](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2225), letting me believe there is some quirk here?

The (naive) factory I'm currently working with is implemented as follows, JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper being one of my own classes:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

public class JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapperFactory implements Factory<JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper> {
    private final HttpServletRequest request;
    private final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams;

    @Inject
    public JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapperFactory(HttpServletRequest request, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
        this.request = request;
        this.formParams = formParams;
    }

    @Override
    public JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper provide() {
        return new JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper(request, formParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper jerseyHttpServletRequestWrapper) {
    }
}
```

I'm thinking here that an entity provider should be injected into the instance so that I can check if there is actually an entity sent with the request. Trying to directly inject MultivaluedMap errors out with:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=MultivaluedMap<String,String>,parent=JerseyHttpServletRequestWrapperFactory,qualifiers={},position=1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2067821943)
```

Comment: This is not the kind of question you should ask on SO. You need to show us what you've done so far - give us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
@POST
public Response post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) {}
```

this method parameter injection is handled differently than with regular field/constructor injection. So you can't try to inject the `MultivaluedMap` into a field.

What you can do though is inject the `ContainerRequest`, and then read the body. You'll want to check that it's a POST request and the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If you don't, there's a chance you will get an exception when you try to read the entity.

```
@Inject
ContainerRequest request;

if (request.getMethod().toUpperCase().equals("POST")
     && request.getMediaType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)) {
    request.bufferEntity();
    Form form = request.readEntity(Form.class);
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = form.asMap();
}
```